# AngularJS dropdown working in Firefox not in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the dropdown for different options ID is different with that one API will be called.

HTML :

```
<select id="select">
    <option ng-repeat="p in projects | unique:'pId'" value="{{p.pId}}"
            ng-model="p.pName" ng-click="onSelectClick(p.pId)"
            ng-selected="{{p.pId == selectedId}}">{{p.pName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var pDetails = {
                    "pId": pId,
                    "pName": pName,
                        }
$scope.Projects.push(pDetails);
```

Comment: What you mean by not working?

Comment: in chrome I am unable to select the option.

Comment: after selecting ng-change or ng-click is not working.

Comment: remove `ng-model` ad try

Comment: after selecting an option , API should call with respect to that option. It is working fine in firefox but in chrome there is an issue.

some dev's are suggesting that use ng-change with model insted of ng-click.
How to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML :

```
 <select data-ng-model="Pdetail" data-ng-options="d.Id as d.Name for d in   
orderedProjects" class="form-control">`                                                              
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
```

And in JS:

```
 $scope.orderedProjects = {};
 var projectDetails = { "projectId": projectId, "projectName":projectName};         
 $scope.orderedProjects.push(projectDetails);
```

Comment: thanks for the ans. but ng-change is not working after selecting the option

Comment: can you place a ng-change="function(id,name)". I did but it is not working. Thanks

Comment: Add in HTML: ng-change="ordPro()" and in JS : $scope.ordPro = function(){ var OrdPro = $scope.Pdetail; }. In data-ng-option it select the Id of orderProjects,,so u don't need to add parameter in ng-change function